# Telling the time "3:15" in American English

Tags: american-english, time, stress

Which of the followings is the most common way to say *3:15* in American English?

> 1. A quarter past three
> 2. A quarter after three
> 3. Three fifteen

Also, in the last example "three fifteen", where do you put the stress (fif-TEEN or FIF-teen)?

Comment: Just curious, are you asking as a Brit, or a non-native-English speaker?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61929/how-should-i-describe-245/61952#61952

Comment: I think 1 and 3 are both equally common.

Comment: As a non-native speaker. I'm more inclined to use American English but we learned the "X after Y" form in school (British English.)

Comment: @Fabien: as a British English speaker I would never say *a quarter after three*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's most commonly *three fifteen* /ˈθri fɪfˈtin/.  In the latter word, the stress is on *teen*.

The other two choices are also fine, with *past* somewhat more common than *after*.  The article *a* isn't always included.

Comment: Agreed.  In these days of digital clocks, *three fifteen* is becoming even more common than in the past.  And (for 2:45) *quarter of three* is losing ground against *two forty-five*.